# Text in my button cuts from below

Tags: android, android-button

I have 5 buttons having a 9 patch image set as its background.
but text in those buttons gets cut from below.
i was previously using another image with slightly more pixels in height.
that worked perfectly but i want to use this image now.
my previous image was 185 X 46
and current image is 185 X 41.

should it make any defference afterall they are 9patch.they should stretch accordingly.
Please have a look at this screenshot.Thanks.
[image]

this is xml code for my button

```
               <Button
                android:id="@+id/SplBtn"
                style="@style/shadowed_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:text="@string/monthlyspecialsStr" />
```

and this is style for those buttons.

```
<style name="shadowed_button">
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/button_textcolor_selector</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">5dip</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">1.5</item>
        <item  name="android:background">@drawable/button_background_selector_arrow</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">40dip</item>
    </style>
```

[image: 9 patch image]

Comment: Show your Nine Patch Screen shot if possible , how you added pixels?

Comment: @Venky please have a look @ this 9 patch

Comment: Problem is you don't added pixels properly.. You should handle it. For Testing if you have any other 9 patch image set it as Background and try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your 9 patch coordination points.Lets extends the vertical and horizontal points to be full extent in your 9 patch image.

Comment: @Senthil still not done either text completely goes out or is shown as in screenshot. 've tried giving full border from left and top.

Comment: Why you gave height in style and also inside Button?

Comment: @Venky 
:) removed now. but still no success.

Comment: @Shash, the image you have shown here is not an correct coordinates marked.try to mark on vertical points to be full extent and remove your fixed height from your layout.